# How can I redirect from an URL to a Codename One app?

Tags: java, redirect, codenameone

I'm trying to make an app with Codename One, where you have to login with OAuth 2 from a specific webservice. After the login  on the webpage, it should redirect to my app. But I don't know, where in Codename One I have to set the redirect URL. Are there some build hints I could use?
I tried it with the Login class and there I set the redirect URI, but it's not working.

Comment: You can see the "Intercepting URL" section here https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html but normally people just use OAuth to login using a browser within the app itself. For that we have an OAuth2 class builtin or you can just embed a browser component and bind a navigation listener to it.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I already tried it with the OAuth2 class and a browser component, but it isn't working. I always get an error: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME and it's trying to load another url and not my redirect url.

Comment: If the OAUTH sends to a URL like `myurlscheme://mydata` then you need grab that in a navigation listener and swallow that URL. Alternatively you can read the intercepting URL's section... I would suggest adding code and explaining in more detail the failure that happened, it sounds like you were on the right direction and might need a small nude to get it working

Answer (score 2):

When you register your application with an Oauth provider you will need to specify the redirection url . The oauth server will redirect once authentication is successfull.

Have a look at https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/